# [R package]ubuntu 18.04 have trouble installing R packages("forecast")

Tags: r

ubuntu 18.04 have trouble installing forecast package.

R version:

```
henry@henry-Z360-MFLGL:~$ R --version
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
```

I have no idea what is wrong with it:

```
> install.packages('forecast')
Installing package into ‘/home/henry/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: dependency ‘quadprog’ is not available
also installing the dependency ‘tseries’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tseries_0.10-46.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 164471 bytes (160 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 160 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/forecast_8.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 909190 bytes (887 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 887 KB

ERROR: dependency ‘quadprog’ is not available for package ‘tseries’
* removing ‘/home/henry/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tseries’
ERROR: dependency ‘tseries’ is not available for package ‘forecast’
* removing ‘/home/henry/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/forecast’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpLRXSdv/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘tseries’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've tried
`sudo -i R`, and etc. but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Update to the latest R version.  `quadprog` package depends on R version 3.6.0.  See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/index.html)

Comment: As an alternative, you can use my package [`oldr`](https://github.com/duckmayr/oldr) to install a suitable version of `quadprog` for your old version of R, if for some reason you can't or won't update R. In this case I wouldn't recommend it, because it's at least possible `forecast` or some package it depends on may rely on some feature in the latest version of `quadprog`, but the option is there if you need it.

Comment: @duckmayr Thanks for the reply! I choose to reinstall latest version of R. it seem to be easier for me to solve the problem :)